# Climate Change Review paper

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, climate-science

Could anybody recommend me some review paper on climate change or tell me some major names in that field? I work in a completely different area but I would like to learn about the current state of our knowledge regarding this subject. In particular I am interested in currently accepted forecasts, the human impact on the current trends etc..

Comment: While I don't think that this is off-topic here, you might find more concentrated expertise on [earthscience.se].

Comment: As a reminder to all, comments are not for discussion nor for posting answers. If you have resources that fit the needs of OP, please post them as an answer (and provide details like needed for all resource-requests). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course the most authoritative review paper is the IPCC report. 
You may find the latest report, the fifth revision, AR5, at the webpage: https://www.ipcc.ch/reports/ 
Depending on your background / time, you may like to first read the Synthesis Report and even Summary for Policy Makers. In the main report, consisting of many volumes, you may find technical explanation and references.

Comment: perfect, thank you for the reference!